# Flux of a vector field that is a partial derivative

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, vector-fields

> Let $X = \partial_x$ and $Y = x \partial_y$ be vectorfields on $M =  \mathbb{R}^2$

I want to calculate the flux of $X$ and $Y$. I am confused on how to approach this problem. 
The formula to calculate the flux of a vector field is:
$$\Phi = \int_S F \cdot dS$$
However, If I use $F = \partial_x$ we obtain:
$$\int_S \partial_x \cdot dS$$
which doesn't make a lot of sense to me

Edit: $S$ refers to a surface, meaning that I am using a surface integral

Comment: What is the variable S?

Comment: @nls It just means that I am integrating over a surface S

Comment: You can make the (vectorial) identification $X= (1,0)$ and $Y= (0,x)$.

Comment: @peterag I guess that I have to integrate X and Y over R^2. Now I am not sure what kind of surface I have to integrate

Comment: I must confess I did not look carefully at the question.   I am adding a 'comment' in the 'answer' section.

Comment: So the flux is across the *boundary* of a compact region $S\subset\Bbb R^2$? This question makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is ALMOST not an answer, but a follow-up comment.

In the language of vector calculus: when $S$ is a region in the plane, the flux $\Phi$ of a vector field $F$ is calculated across the boundary $\partial  S$ of $S$:
$$ \Phi = \int_{\partial S} F\cdot n\, ds,$$
where $n$ is the outward normal, and $ds$ is the length element (i.e., the integral is one dimensional).

But, by the divergence/Gauss theorem, one can also calculate the flux $\Phi$ by the formula
$$ \Phi= \int_S \mathop{\text{div}} F\, dA,$$
where the integral is now an area integral (i.e., a double integral), and $dA$ is an area element, and $\mathop{\text{div}} F$ is the divergence of $F$ (which is often also denoted $\nabla\cdot F$).

Typically one needs to know $S$ (or $\partial S$). However! In your case, the divergence theorem is pretty relevant (i.e., hint: calculate the divergence!) - I am assuming you know it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I didn't think of using Gauss' theorem. thanks

Comment: Thank you very much.....for your recent comment...and +1 for you.